# How to append columns based on other column values to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append, dataframe

I have the following problem: I want to append columns to a dataframe. These columns are the unique values in another row of this dataframe, filled with the occurence of this value in this row. It looks like this:

```
df:

   Column1  Column2
0     1       a,b,c
1     2       a,e
2     3       a
3     4       c,f
4     5       c,f
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
    Column1  Column2  a  b  c  e  f
0     1       a,b,c   1  1  1
1     2       a,e     1        1
2     3       a       1
3     4       c,f           1     1
4     5       c,f           1     1
```

(the empty spaces can be nan or 0, it matters not.)

I have now written some code to aceive this, but instead of appending columns, it appends rows, so that my output looks like this:

```
        Column1  Column2
    0     1       a,b,c
    1     2       a,e
    2     3       a
    3     4       c,f
    4     5       c,f
    a     1        1
    b     1        1
    c     1        1
    e     1        1
    f     1        1
```

The code looks like this:

```
def NewCols(x):
    for i, value in df['Column2'].iteritems():
        listi=value.split(',')
        for value in listi:
            string = value
            x[string]=list.count(string)
    return x

df1=df.apply(NewCols)
```

What I am trying to do here is to iterate through each row of the dataframe and split the string (a,b,c) contained in Column2 at comma, so the variable `listi`
is then a list containing the separated string values. For each of this values I then want to make a new column and fill it with the number of occurences of that value in `listi`. I am confused why the code appends rows instead of columns. Does somebody know why and how I can correct that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we could do this using `get_dummies`, we can also cheat and use `pd.value_counts` directly:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'Column2': {0: 'a,b,c', 1: 'a,e', 2: 'a', 3: 'c,f', 4: 'c,f'}})
>>> df.join(df.Column2.str.split(",").apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0))
   Column1 Column2  a  b  c  e  f
0        1   a,b,c  1  1  1  0  0
1        2     a,e  1  0  0  1  0
2        3       a  1  0  0  0  0
3        4     c,f  0  0  1  0  1
4        5     c,f  0  0  1  0  1
```

---

Step-by-step, we have

```
>>> df.Column2.str.split(",")
0    [a, b, c]
1       [a, e]
2          [a]
3       [c, f]
4       [c, f]
dtype: object
>>> df.Column2.str.split(",").apply(pd.value_counts)
    a   b   c   e   f
0   1   1   1 NaN NaN
1   1 NaN NaN   1 NaN
2   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN   1 NaN   1
4 NaN NaN   1 NaN   1
>>> df.Column2.str.split(",").apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
   a  b  c  e  f
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  1
4  0  0  1  0  1
>>> df.join(df.Column2.str.split(",").apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0))
   Column1 Column2  a  b  c  e  f
0        1   a,b,c  1  1  1  0  0
1        2     a,e  1  0  0  1  0
2        3       a  1  0  0  0  0
3        4     c,f  0  0  1  0  1
4        5     c,f  0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Works perfekt, thank you for the detailed explanation, I get it :-).

Comment: Why is using `value_counts` rather than `get_dummies` considered cheating? :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `apply`, it calls your function once for each column, with that column as an argument.  So `x` in your NewCols will be set to a single column.  When you do `x[string] = list.count(string)`, you are adding values to that column.  Since `apply` is called for *each* column, you wind up appending the values to both columns in this way.

`apply` is not the right choice when your computation depends only on the values of a single column.  Instead, use `map`.  In this case, what you need to do is write a NewCol function that accepts a single `Column2` value and returns the data for a single row.  You can return this as a dict, or, handily, a dict-like object such as a `collections.Counter`.  Then you need to wrap this new row data into a DataFrame and attach it column-wise to your existing data using `concat`.  Here is an example:

```
def NewCols(val):
    return collections.Counter(val.split(','))

>>> pandas.concat([d, pandas.DataFrame.from_records(d.Column2.map(NewCols))], axis=1)
   Column1 Column2   a   b   c   e   f
0        1   a,b,c   1   1   1 NaN NaN
1        2     a,e   1 NaN NaN   1 NaN
2        3       a   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3        4     c,f NaN NaN   1 NaN   1
4        5     c,f NaN NaN   1 NaN   1
```

For this particular computation, you actually don't need to write your own function at all, because pandas has `split` built in as an operation under the `.str` method accessor.  So you can do this:

```
>>> pandas.concat([d, pandas.DataFrame.from_records(d.Column2.str.split(',').map(collections.Counter))], axis=1)
   Column1 Column2   a   b   c   e   f
0        1   a,b,c   1   1   1 NaN NaN
1        2     a,e   1 NaN NaN   1 NaN
2        3       a   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3        4     c,f NaN NaN   1 NaN   1
4        5     c,f NaN NaN   1 NaN   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! However the code raises a key error for me...`KeyError: 0L` Any idea what the cause could be?

Comment: @sequence_hard: Not sure, I can't reproduce that error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something as:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text

vect = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(binary=True,   token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
df = ...
v = [a for a in df['Column2']]
new_df = df.combine_first( pd.DataFrame(vect.fit_transform(v).todense(), columns=vect.get_feature_names()) )
print new_df
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can improve your answer by annotating the code!