# Python pandas - value_counts not working properly

Tags: python, pandas

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373030/how-to-append-columns-based-on-other-column-values-to-pandas-dataframe) post on stack i tried the value counts function like this

`df2 = df1.join(df1.genres.str.split(",").apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0))`

and it works fine apart from the fact that although my data has 22 unique genres and after the split i get 42 values, which of course are not unique.
Data example:

```
     Action  Adventure   Casual  Design & Illustration   Early Access    Education   Free to Play    Indie   Massively Multiplayer   Photo Editing   RPG     Racing  Simulation  Software Training   Sports  Strategy    Utilities   Video Production    Web Publishing Accounting  Action  Adventure   Animation & Modeling    Audio Production    Casual  Design & Illustration   Early Access    Education   Free to Play    Indie   Massively Multiplayer   Photo Editing   RPG Racing  Simulation  Software Training   Sports  Strategy    Utilities   Video Production    Web Publishing  nan
0   nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan 1.0 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

(i have pasted the head and the first row only)

I have a feeling that the problem is caused from my original data.Well, my column (genres) was a list of lists which contained brackets

example :`[Action,Indie]`
so when python was reading it, it would read [Action and Action and Action] as different values and the output was 303 different values. 
So what i did is that:

```
for i in df1['genres'].tolist():
if str(i) != 'nan':

    i = i[1:-1]
    new.append(i)
else:
    new.append('nan')
```

Comment: You can try: `if str(i).notnull():`

Comment: Can you show me your input data `df1`, 5 - 6 rows?

Comment: But I think you can use: `print df['genres'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')`

Comment: Ok i have found the problem, but i am not sure how to solve it. My header data, meaning the genres has issues with spaces. Meaning that Action appears as [space]Action , Action , Action(space)

Comment: remove this space is possible by function `strip()`

Comment: Yea i have seen that, but i just cant do it. I am trying but i cant find the correct way.

Comment: Do i put it at the line with the split? like this 

`df2=df1.join(df1.genres.str.split(",").split().apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0))`

Comment: I have an idea - Can you upload your input csv to dropbox or wetransfer and post me it link? I would like to help you, but without file it is impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97069/discussion-between-thodoris-p-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove first and last `[]` from column `genres` by function [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then replace spaces by empty string by function [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test/Copy of AppCrawler.csv', sep="\t")


df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.strip('[]')
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.replace(' ', '')

df = df.join(df.genres.str.split(",").apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0))

#temporaly display 30 rows and 60 columns
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 30, 'display.max_columns', 60):
    print df
    #remove for clarity
print df.columns
Index([u'Unnamed: 0', u'appid', u'currency', u'final_price', u'genres',
       u'initial_price', u'is_free', u'metacritic', u'release_date',
       u'Accounting', u'Action', u'Adventure', u'Animation&Modeling',
       u'AudioProduction', u'Casual', u'Design&Illustration', u'EarlyAccess',
       u'Education', u'FreetoPlay', u'Indie', u'MassivelyMultiplayer',
       u'PhotoEditing', u'RPG', u'Racing', u'Simulation', u'SoftwareTraining',
       u'Sports', u'Strategy', u'Utilities', u'VideoProduction',
       u'WebPublishing'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Just what i needed! I dont understand what you are doing with the "with" statement. Couldn't you just print df?

Comment: Maybe [In 19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#getting-and-setting-options) better explains.